# Automatically make post and tag relationships in a CakePHP blog

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm writing a pretty simple blogging application using CakePHP to help me learn the framework. Blog posts can have many tags, and tags can belong to many blog posts (like on StackOverflow). Here's my database schema with foreign keys to reflect this:

[image]

I have set up a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship between my `Post` and `Tag` models with CakePHP (I think this is the right way to do it?), which looks like this:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Tag',
                'foreignKey'             => 'post_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'tag_id',
                'unique'                 => true
            )
    );
}

class Tag extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Tag';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className'              => 'Post',
            'foreignKey'             => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'post_id',
            'unique'                 => true
        )
    );
}
```

I also have a really simple page set up for adding posts, the view for that looks like this:

```
<h1>Add blog post</h1>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('body'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('slug'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Publish'); ?>
```

My question is, is it possible to have an input field on my add page where I can type in tag names (separated by a space) and then have Cake automatically make the relationships in my database? Much like the way StackOverflow does it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change Table name "posts_tags" to "post_tags" and add field

```
"joinTable" => "post_tags";
```

in HABTM function
and how you are adding tags?? From same view or other view??

Answer (score 0):

Check our plugin out https://github.com/cakedc/tags

It is exactly doing that and you can integrate it with just a few lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather implement this myself. Like I said I'm doing this for learning purposes so just dragging in a plugin won't teach me much, although I'll look through your code, thanks!